# Why don't you let me delete the item in my code with Node.js and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently learning NodeJS and I try to make an application where Bicicleta is added but it does not let me delete them for more than the message of the POST of the delete, it is 200 (success) but I get that my model has not been modified (304) of course in the interface it looks so that even if I click on the Delete button it does not delete the item.

I share the code **../models/bicycle.js**

```
Bicicleta.removeById = function(aBiciId){
    for(var i = 0; i < Bicicleta.allBicis.length; i++){
        if(Bicicleta.allBicis[i].id == aBiciId){
            Bicicleta.allBicis.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }

    }
}
module.exports = Bicicleta;
```

I also insert the controller code **../controllers/bicycle.js**

```
  bicicleta_delete_post = function(req, res){
     Bicicleta.removeById(req.body.id);

     res.redirect('/bicicletas');
```

**./routes/bicicleta.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bicicletaController = require('../controllers/bicicleta');

router.post('/:id/delete', bicicletaController.bicicleta_delete_post);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: can you try changing the content of `exports.bicicleta_delete_post` function into `arr.splice(aBiciId, 1)`

Comment: and can you put `console.log(aBiciId)` in your model's `removeById` and show what it outputs ?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw I should put the console.log of my removeById function before to change the content of my exports.bicicleta_delete_post

Comment: try `console.log(aBiciId)` first. I will just check if the ID indeed exists.

Comment: If I put the console after of Bicicleta.allBicis.splice(i, 1); the console.log result is undefined. If I put it before, don´t show the log

Comment: I see so probably the problem is in your controller. Can you try putting `console.log(req.body)` in the `bicicleta_delete_post ` and see what the result is ?

Comment: I just tried with console.log(req.body) and result error

Comment: What error did it show @Jean ?

Comment: Not Found
404
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at D:\node-red-bicicletas\app.js:29:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node-red-bicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\node-red-bicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\node-red-bicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\node-red-bicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)

Comment: at next (D:\node-red-bicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at D:\node-red-bicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (D:\node-red-bicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (D:\node-red-bicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\node-red-bicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206264/discussion-between-jean-gotopo-and-karma-blackshaw).

Answer (score 0):

Using route parameters like `router.post('/:id/delete', bicicletaController.bicicleta_delete_post);` will end up with `id` being in `req.params.id`, not in `req.body.id`.

This means you essentially do `removeById(undefined)`, which does nothing.

I'd recommend (aside from changing `req.body` to `req.params`)  also making the deletion function throw an error if it can't delete anything:

```
Bicicleta.removeById = function(aBiciId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Bicicleta.allBicis.length; i++) {
    if (Bicicleta.allBicis[i].id == aBiciId) {
      return Bicicleta.allBicis.splice(i, 1);  // return deleted object
    }
  }
  throw new Error(`No Bicicleta to delete with id ${aBiciId}`);
};
```

Comment: Someone edited my question, and deleted the app.js code, and I just get an error on line 29 of app.js:

Not Found
404
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at D: \ node-red-bicycles \ app.js: 29: 8

and this is the line:

 app.use (function (req, res, next) {
  next (createError (404));
  console.log ('You made a mistake');
});

Comment: I throw this error to test your recommendation: Error: No Bicicleta to delete with id undefined

Comment: Did you also change `req.body.id` to be `req.params.id` like I said?

Comment: Where would i change it?